# How to write an efficient custom Keras data generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to train a convolutional recurrent neural network for video frame prediction. The individual frames are quite big so it is challenging to fit the entire training data in memory at once. As such, I followed some tutorials online to create a custom data generator. When testing it, it seems to work but it is slower by a factor of at least 100 than using the pre-loaded data directly. Since I can only fit about a batch size of 8 on the GPU I understand that the data needs to be generated really fast, however, this does not seem to be the case.

I train my model on a single P100 and have 32 GB of memory available to be used by up to 16 cores.

```
class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

def __init__(self, images, input_images=5, predict_images=5, batch_size=16, image_size=(200, 200),
             channels=1):

    self.images = images
    self.input_images = input_images
    self.predict_images = predict_images
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.image_size = image_size
    self.channels = channels
    self.nr_images = int(len(self.images)-input_images-predict_images)

def __len__(self):

    return int(np.floor(self.nr_images) / self.batch_size)

def __getitem__(self, item):

    # Randomly select the beginning image of each batch
    batch_indices = random.sample(range(0, self.nr_images), self.batch_size)

    # Allocate the output images
    x = np.empty((self.batch_size, self.input_images,
                  *self.image_size, self.channels), dtype='uint8')
    y = np.empty((self.batch_size, self.predict_images,
                  *self.image_size, self.channels), dtype='uint8')

    # Get the list of input an prediction images
    for i in range(self.batch_size):
        list_images_input = range(batch_indices[i], batch_indices[i]+self.input_images)
        list_images_predict = range(batch_indices[i]+self.input_images,
                                         batch_indices[i]+self.input_images+self.predict_images)

        for j, ID in enumerate(list_images_input):
            x[i, ] = np.load(np.reshape(self.images[ID], (*self.imagesize, self.channels))

        # Read in the prediction images
        for j, ID in enumerate(list_images_predict):
            y[i, ] = np.load(np.reshape(self.images[ID], (*self.imagesize, self.channels))

    return x, y


# Training the model using fit_generator

params = {'batch_size': 8,
      'input_images': 5,
      'predict_images': 5,
      'image_size': (100, 100),
      'channels': 1
      }

data_path = "input_frames/"
input_images = sorted(glob.glob(data_path + "*.png"))
training_generator = DataGenerator(input_images, **params)

model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator, epochs=10, workers=6)
```

I would have expected that Keras will prepare the next data batch while the current batch is being processed on the GPU but it does not seem to catch up. In other words, preparing the data before sending it to the GPU seems to be the bottleneck.

Any idea on how to improve the performance of a data generator like this? Is there something missing that guarantees that the data is being prepared in a timely manner?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am having a similar problem when using a simple generator. It takes 10 minutes or more to get a sample.

Comment: No, I was not. But in Tensorflow 2 there is a data class that allows one to build a proper input pipeline. I think this would be the place to start now.

Answer (score 0):

When you use fit_generator, there is a workers= setting that can be used to scale up the number of generator workers. However you should ensure that the 'item' parameter in **getitem** is taken into account in order to ensure that the different workers (which are not synchronised) return different values depending on item index. i.e. instead of random sample, perhaps just return a slice of the data based on the index. You can shuffle the entire dataset before starting in order to make sure the dataset order is randomised.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with use_multiprocessing=True? These are the numbers I observe on my GTX 1080Ti based system with the data generator you provided.

```
model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator, epochs=10, workers=6)
```

148/148 [==============================] - **9s 60ms/step**

```
model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator, epochs=10, workers=6, use_multiprocessing=True)
```

148/148 [==============================] - **2s 11ms/step**

Comment: I tried this but it still is considerably slower than using no data generator at all. With the preloaded data I can get one epoch done in about 10 minutes, with the data generator (and use_multiprocessing=True) it will take about 3 hours and 30 minutes, which is unacceptable. I still don't know why this takes so much time, in particular since I do nothing fancy in my generator. I have seen data generators that do on the fly image resizing which I would assume has to be way more expensive than just loading prepared numpy files.

Comment: What is the count of training images? Also, looks like you made some edits before posting the code because there are some syntactic errors. Maybe you can profile the code by invoking the generator yourself. Also, look at the CPU utilization etc.

Comment: There are a total of 12000 training videos of 5 frames each. Yes, I did edit the code a bit to make it more concise for my question. I can give profiling a shot but am still surprised why this relatively simple generator would take more time than the custom data generators found online that do image resizing on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the prefetching of `tf.data.Dataset`. The prefetching allows you to compute the next batch(es) using your CPU while your GPU computes the gradient descent in the same time. Be careful: you need to change the numpy array into `tf.constant` in the data generator. Then try:

```py
import tensoflow as tf

generator = DataGenerator(images)
spec = [tf.TypeSpec(shape=(generator.batch_size, generator.input_images,
                  *generator.image_size, generator.channels), dtype='uint8'),
        tf.TypeSpec(shape=(generator.batch_size, generator.predict_images,
                  *generator.image_size, generator.channels), dtype='uint8')
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(DataGenerator, output_signature=spec)
dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(-1) # this order is important

# a custom training loop is better than model.fit() otherwise prefetching can fail
def train_loop(): 
    ...
```

You can change the "-1" in `prefetch()` to another value like 1, 2 or more to get the maximum speed depending on your machine and the batch size.

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://quantumai.in/tf-data/) blog helps in setting up input data pipeline with tf.data and it also is much more efficient than using **ImageDataGenerators** and the code is also explained by using a custom data directory.
It also enhances the performance with **prefetch**, **cache**.

**Prefetch** processes the next batch while the current batch is being used.